# What is the verb for knowing that I exist?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

English is not my first language, therefore my vocabulary isn't so fabulous.

I am describing the later stages of Alzheimer disease, and I am including some of the main key points.

For this part also, I am stuck. The phrase I am working on goes like so:

> They lose the ability to memorize. To understand. To [verb for awareness of own existence]

I am mainly looking for just one verb that fits this requirement - in other words, one verb that can change: 'the ability to know that they exist' as this one sounds too tacky.

Comment: There's no verb. You could do it with nouns: *They lose memory. Understanding. Self-awareness.*

Comment: To be aware of themselves.

Comment: I would say that "self-aware" is the adjective, and "be/is self-aware" gives you a verb.

Comment: @StoneyB You should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might go with the hyphenated verb ***self-cognize***, as in "They lose the ability to memorize. To understand. To self-cognize."

To ***cognize*** means "to perceive; become conscious of; know" ([here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cognize)).

Thus, to ***self-cognize*** means "to perceive or become conscious of or know one's self." This is tantamount to knowing one exists.

Answer (score 2):

There are no words I'm aware of that fit the bill precisely, but here are a few suggestions:

- *Reflect*
- *Bethink*
- *Meditate*
- *Introspect*

If these don't satisfy you you can sort of 'cheat' by just plopping the word 'self' in front of a given word (like 'self-reflect' or 'self-study'). Although it isn't technically 'proper', your reader will surely understand what you're trying to say, and that's really the goal of language anyway. If you can make it sound as though it *should* be a word, and if it has a clear meaning, feel free to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to drop a particular style in favour of another. As many users have already mentioned, there is no verb in English which means "knowledge of one's existence". The terms **id** (the part of the mind in which innate instinctive impulses and primary processes are manifest), **ego**, and **superego** are sometimes used in connection with Alzheimer.

> - ... manifestations become murky as the clinical course of Alzheimer's disease advances. Generally, *ego* dysfunction is considerably more apparent than *superego* ...
> - Those at endstage dementia have been regarded psychodynamically as experiencing a complete breakdown of the *ego* and its defences with apparent reciprocal dedifferentiation of the *id*.
>   [[source]](https://books.google.it/books?id=1BZa7fxtRcAC&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=superego%20alzheimer&source=bl&ots=iI60MPmyzD&sig=Idt2A9dBX744w8Ce7ZimZf1EjSY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy-Pi7jK7MAhUHOhQKHdwjD4gQ6AEIOjAH#v=onepage&q=superego%20alzheimer&f=false)

However, it's my understanding that these Freudian terms have become dated, and not everyone agrees with their definitions. But don't quote me on that.

A newly coined term,  **“aware ego”** (*[The Neurobiology
of the Aware Ego](http://delos-inc.com/articles-b/Neurobiology_Of_The_Aware_Ego.pdf)*) appears to have replaced Freud's [Id, Ego and Superego](http://www.simplypsychology.org/psyche.html), but I don't know how common or well-known this expression is. In the same medical article, the term  **[anosognosia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anosognosia)** (lack of self awareness) is used.

Instead, may I suggest a different solution which covers all five of the above, and is easily understandable; **identity loss**. *Google Scholar* has about 58,600 hits for [Alzheimer's identitiy loss](https://scholar.google.it/scholar?q=Alzheimer%27s%20and%20identity%20loss&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1) (without speech marks). Swapping verbs with nouns would lead to this formation.

> They **lose** their memory. Their understanding. Their **identity**